# Naked domain redirect to www not working with https

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, g-suite

http://zetetic.technology/ redirects to https://www.zetetic.technology/ just fine, but redirecting https://zetetic.technology/ results in "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" in Chrome.

My site is hosted by g suite, and my domain cname records are controlled by 123 reg. I have set the following cname records

```
DNS ENTRY   TYPE    PRIORITY    TTL DESTINATION/TARGET
@   A           216.239.32.21
@   A           216.239.32.21
@   A           216.239.36.21
@   A           216.239.38.21
@   AAAA            2001:4860:4802:32::1...
@   AAAA            2001:4860:4802:34::1...
@   AAAA            2001:4860:4802:36::1...
@   AAAA            2001:4860:4802:38::1...
www CNAME           ghs.googlehosted.com...
```

Am I missing one somewhere?

Comment: From the outside, I am getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, not ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. It doesn't seem like a DNS issue.

Comment: It rather seems that you need a *301 redirect* as describered [here](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en). At least your `http://zetetic.technology/` does this to `http://www.zetetic.technology/` which then further redirects to `https://www.zetetic.technology/`.

Comment: You may need to get a certificate that covers `zetetic.technology` as well, and not just `www.zetetic.technology`. It may be that g suite is refusing to initiate the HTTPS connection because it doesn't have a valid cert for `zetetic.technology` (Unless you have configured a separate cert for each hostname)

Comment: Not related to your problem but you have `216.239.32.21` twice, which is useless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever Google is hosting this on is not configured for SSL on your naked domain and as such is just closing the connection.

I would be contacting Google support about this issue, as I doubt anyone in the public is going to be able to tell you what's going on.

Comment: This is indeed the case, it is not a DNS problem but purely a TCP/TLS one, `openssl s_client -connect zetetic.technology:443 -servername zetetic.technology` clearly shows the remote end is unwilling to start a TLS handshake. So this seems to be a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is most likely complaining because you are redirecting from an insecure domain (http://zetetic.technology) to a secure domain (https://www.zetetic.technology), which causes security vulnerability. To get around this, make sure that your certificate includes www.zetetic.technology as the common name or subject *and* includes both forms of the name (www.zetetic.technology and zetetic.technology) as SANs (subject alternat names). Once you do this, Google will trust the entire redirection path without seeing a security risk.

Comment: Modern browsers do not take into account the CN anymore, only the SANs. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5937270/6368697

Comment: True, but the key point is that both the named domain and the www child domain name need to be listed on the cert.